# How do I use environment markers with requirements files in setup.cfg?

Tags: python

I have dependencies which I would like to pull in via a test-requirements file which is dependent on the environment

```
[testenv]
deps =
    setuptools
    -r test-requirements.lock.txt ; sys_platform == 'win32'
    -r test-requirements-linux.lock.txt ; sys_platform == 'linux'
```

The problem I am facing is that the environment markers are ignored when using `-r`.

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "test-requirements.lock.txt ; sys_platform == 'win32'"`
```

However, the `-r` is required to denote that the dependency is a requirements file.

How can I pull in the correct requirements file depending on environment markers in setup.cfg?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make use of tox's platform specifications: https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/platform.html

```
[testenv]
deps =
    setuptools
    linux: -rtest-requirements-linux.lock.txt
    windows: -rtest-requirements.lock.txt
```